# How to show Save success message in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 5.1, I can save the data in the database. But I would like to show a success message. How can I do it? My code in Controller save code is

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required|unique:seeders|max:255',
        'address'=>'required`enter code here`',
        'age'=>'required',
    ]);

    $seeder=new Seeders();
    $seeder->name=$request->input('name');
    $seeder->address=$request->input('address');
    $seeder->age=$request->input('age');
    $seeder->save();

    return redirect()->route("photo.index");
} // save data
```

Comment: after saveing your $seeder, you are redirecting the user, but for showing a success message you need a view. instead of redirect you should render a view with your success message. inside that view, you can insert a link so that user can go to "photo.index"

Answer (score 87):

Just adding this code before your redirect code:

```
$request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'User was successful added!');
```

So the fully code is like here:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // your function

    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'User was successful added!');
    return redirect()->route("photo.index");
}
```

Laravel 5.4 about Flash Data: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data

and for your view:

```
<div class="flash-message">
    @foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
      @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))

      <p class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }} <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a></p>
      @endif
    @endforeach
  </div> <!-- end .flash-message -->
```

You can use Bootstrap Alerts view: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp

Comment: You can change the href on the dismiss anchor to be `javascript:void(0)` instead of `#` and that will stop the click from scrolling to the top on Chrome.

Answer (score 17):

use the code

```
return redirect()->route("photo.index")->with('message','Success');
```

and in you template

```
@if(session('message'))
  {{session('message')}}
@endif
```

Comment: How to make this message to appear in a short time

Comment: @SwR you can more description you trouble? You message appear but does not disappear, or you whant show this message in 1-2 or more page?

Comment: @SwR check out how to use a `data-expires` attribute similar to this:

`@if(session('message'))
<div data-expires="5000">
  {{session('message')}}
</div>
@endif`

Comment: @Ciuc:Thank you...:-)

Answer (score 12):

Very easy

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required|unique:seeders|max:255',
        'address'=>'required`enter code here`',
        'age'=>'required',
    ]);

    $seeder=new Seeders();
    $seeder->name=$request->input('name');
    $seeder->address=$request->input('address');
    $seeder->age=$request->input('age');
    $seeder->save();

    //PUT HERE AFTER YOU SAVE
    \Session::flash('flash_message','successfully saved.');

    return redirect()->route("photo.index");
} // save data
```

In your main view, or index
add this.

```
@if(Session::has('flash_message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><em> {!! session('flash_message') !!}</em></div>
@endif
```

If you want to have different flash styles check this out [Flash Messages in Laravel 5](http://anytch.com/flash-messages-in-laravel-5/)

Comment: I like this method... i might just create a partial so as to accommodate all kinds of flash messages/alerts that I want

Answer (score 7):

You can redirect user and show him the flash message. The message will be available in view in this way `{{ $message }}`

`return redirect('user/login')->with('message', 'Success!');`

More about this you can find [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data).

Answer (score 7):

Show success message with close button:

Controller code:

```
$seeder->save();    
return redirect('photo.index')->with('status', 'You have successfully Created!');
```

Just paste the below code into your view file.

```
@if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a> {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.5 you can use...

In your controller action:

```
...
return redirect('photo.index')->with('alert-success', 'The data was saved successfully');
```

Then in your template you can use the session helper:

```
@if(session()->has('alert-success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('alert-success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

the best way -> https://github.com/laracasts/flash

just do it flash('Message', 'info')