# How to pass a message to another page in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I have a **controller** like this:

```
public function add(Requests\contactValidation $request){

    if(Auth::check()) {
        $new_array = array();
        $new_array['name'] = $request->name;
        $new_array['email'] = $request->email;
        $new_array['content'] = $request->content;
        contact::create($new_array);
        return back();
    } else {
        return back()->withError('you are not log in');
    }
}
```

And I have this **view**:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $errors->all());
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => you are not log in
)
```

---

**My question:** How can I set a name to that message? I want something like this result:

```
Array
(
    [Name] => you are not log in
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I usually do:

```
return Redirect::to('users/register')->with('message', 'The following errors occurred')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

So, basically you can return with message/messages which is stored as a session and obviously also the errors. Also, you can check the following [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views) to the documentation for detailed understanding.

Further, you can print them as:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
      <p class="alert">{!! Session::get('message') !!}</p>
      @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
          <p>{!! $error !!}</p>
      @endforeach
@endif
```

Obviously, you can change it as per your requirement. Hope it helps.

Comment: Does `with()` function set a message in the *session*?

Comment: It sets a variable named message inside the session. Obviously you can name it the way you want :)

Comment: You can also check the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views (passing data to view)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `withErrors()` to put an array (key-value) with messages (instead of `withError()`).

for example:

```
return back()->withErrors(['Name' => 'you are not log in']);
```

inside your view you can also call:

```
@if( $errors->any() )
<span> {{$errors->first()}} </span>
@endif
```

Comment: it should be `['Name'=> 'you are not log in']`

Comment: thank you .. upvote .. just can you please tell me how can I sent a regular message *(not an error message)* to another page? something like *"your comment has been sent"*

Comment: You can use Session flash methods (before your redirect call) like:
`$request->session()->flash('successMessage', 'your comment has been sent');`, see more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961631/how-to-show-save-success-message-in-laravel-5-1 topic