# Where to use the restriction in this code?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent, laravel-5.8

In this controller I upload an image to the database, but how can I use the restriction? Do I have to use a Validator ? How should it look ?

This is my first project and I started using laravel framework for my degree.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Autqwdh;
```

Comment: What restriction are you trying to impose..?

Comment: extension and size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel Validations for your checks, which returns an `ErrorBag` containing the meaningful error message which you can use [in your blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).

```
$request->validate([
    'image' => 'image|max:5000'
]);
```

---

`image` validator:

> The file under validation must be an image (jpeg, png, bmp, gif, or svg)

`max` validator:

> The field under validation must be less than or equal to a maximum value. Strings, numerics, arrays, and files are evaluated in the same fashion as the size rule.

For other cases check the [Laravel Docs - Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)

Comment: it worked , but i like to use it like this 'image' => 'image', 'max:2048', it is faster, thanks!

Comment: @PaulCatalinAgighioleanu like as an array? I didn't know that, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: no problem, do you know some way tho display the image after uploading ? with a session message or something ? like this   @if(session()->has('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        {{ session('success')}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="img2">
                        <img src="{{$employerimage->image}}">
                    </div>

Comment: I use a simple one like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38832044/4705339 but this guy did a cool implementation - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728671/4705339

Comment: You should give the actual path of image (as url). `example.com/imagineprofil$filename`.

Comment: `<img src="/imagineprofile{{ $employee->image }}">`

Comment: Inspect the URL, that means your path is wrong. Make sure you write your path without `/public`

Comment: <img src="{{asset('/imagineprofil/'.$profileimage->image)}}"> it worked like this. thanks